# Timeline state changes when paused

Tags: unity, animation

I'm working on a [Timeline](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.timeline@1.8/manual/index.html) sequence in Unity (not to be confused with the Animator). There are several animation tracks playing different animations at different parts of the scene.

At one point in the timeline, I send a signal that pauses the Timeline's own `PlayableDirector`. The Timeline pauses as expected, but the animation state of one of the objects with an animation track seems to revert to an earlier part of the timeline. I've tried messing with the Hold settings but it doesn't make any difference. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to add transitions to the Animator component, or set the 'Animator Controller' field to null.

Animation tracks on the Timeline play Animation sequences on Animators in the scene. If the Animator has an Animator Controller asset selected, the Timeline normally overrides the state machine flow of the Animator component. However, when the Timeline *pauses*, control returns to the Animator. If the Animator doesn't include any transitions to the animation state that was playing when the Timeline paused (meaning the Animator on its own would never reach that state), it will revert to the default state.

[image: Animator component with three states but no transitions]

In this example, there is no transition from Part 1 to Part 2 or Part 3. We can use this Animator on a Timeline, and play any of the three animations from the Timeline, but if the Timeline ever pauses, the Animator will immediately revert to "Part 1".

Note that if we have an Animator Controller selected in the Animator component, pausing the Timeline will return control to the Animator, which may cause the Animator Controller to advance to a new state and continue playing animations that you don't want it to play. If you don't want the Animator to do anything when the Timeline is paused, set the 'Animator Controller' to null. The Timeline can still play animations on the Animator when the 'Animator Controller' field is null.